# Create separate columns for counts of occurrences of values in column

Tags: sql

I have a data set that looks similar to this:

| ID | Status |
| --- | --- |
| A | Enabled |
| A | Disabled |
| A | Enabled |
| B | Enabled |
| B | Disabled |

And I want to adjust the data structure so that it looks like

| ID | Count Enabled | Count Disabled |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 1 |

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 'Enabled'  THEN 1 END) AS "Count Enabled",
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 'Disabled' THEN 1 END) AS "Count Disabled"
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Could you think of a way via which I could get the same result without hard coding the different values for Status? Think of a situation in which I have 35 different status and I wouldn't want to write 35 Case when clauses.

Comment: You would need dynamic SQL for that, which basically means you would need to write a SQL script which generates something looking like my answer with variable columns.